# Regular expression not matching the number in the Equation

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, match, exec

I need match the `4 pattern` in equation like this type's

1. `_{num}`
2. `_num`
3. `^{num}`
4. `^num`

So i was created the regex pattern like this

```
/\_(\d+)|\^(\d{1})|\_\{(\d+)\}|\^\{(\d+)\}/g
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sFWNCd/1)**

*This regex demo working perfect match  but apply with javascript code its not working*

```js
var int_reg =/\_(\d+)|\^(\d{1})|\_\{(\d+)\}|\^\{(\d+)\}/g;
    var str = int_reg.exec('\int_5^{3}100x-100=10');
                        console.log(str)
```

Please Tell me what's the problem?.And correct my code with my goal

Thank's

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is nice .but i need match `^num` match only one number  `(\d{1})`  like this see my regex pattern.Without `{}` its match the one number.with `{}` match all numbers inside the `{}`.can you correct your code like this flow

Comment: If you want to match `^1` in `2^1-5` and not `^1` in `2^12-5` add `\b`: `\^(\d)\b`.

Comment: Just got interested if it can really be contracted, but it is not that easy to make it an easy one-liner. You might use `s.match(/[_^](?:(?={\d}){|)\d+/g).map(x=>x.replace(/^\D+/, ""))`, but it will require additional post-process. Else, you will need to capture the number as shown in the duped question.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew .Already i got the answer

Answer (score 1):

It works fine, but the array you get is an array of captures (e.g. stuff matched in `()`) of **one** match operation. To match further, you need to invoke `exec` again, like so:

```js
var int_reg =/\_(\d+)|\^(\d{1})|\_\{(\d+)\}|\^\{(\d+)\}/g;
var str = '\int_5^{3}100x-100=10';
console.log(int_reg.exec(str))
console.log(int_reg.exec(str))
console.log(int_reg.exec(str))
```

**Edit** to address your additional question (even though the question has been closed):

```js
var int_reg =/\_\d+|\^\d|\_\{\d+\}|\^\{\d+\}/g;
var str = '\int_5^{3}100x-100=10';
console.log(str.match(int_reg).map(s => Number((/\d+/.exec(s))[0])))
```

Comment: could you help to match these pattern in single regex ? or out with single ? if Any other possibilities  are there?

Comment: @prasad Not sure I understand what you ask but I have added an edit.